# SharePoint apps are greyed out

Tags: sharepoint-server

I've setup a SharePoint Enterprise 2013 and are trying to install apps from SharePoint store but all the apps (almost) are greyed out. There is two apps that is not inactive, it's SimpleNews and metaEngine Tag Cloud.

I had a dev server (SharePoint Foundation 2013 English) that didn't have any inactive apps (Enterprise apps where inactive though). The SharePoint 2013 that I'm trying to get apps for is a Swedish version and not English like the Foundation.

What is the problem? Is it because of the Swedish language or something I'm missing?

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that it's not the language that is the problem. I've setup a test enviroment and on that server SharePoint store worked greate. What can make the apps be all greyed out? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You're probably missing certain prerequisites for the app. Now normally if you had the app package it'd just be a case of looking at the AppManifest.xml and searching for the `AppPrerequisites` tag to see what services are required on SharePoint before adding the application.

When it comes to apps on the SharePoint Store there are a couple of things you can try checking to determine what prerequisites you're missing.

### 1. ULS logs

Pretty easy, just open your ULS logs and search for the name of the app your trying to install. You should find a line similar to the following:

> SharePoint Foundation
>   App Marketplace
>   ajcnj
>   Medium
>   Prerequisites Checking for App '*App Name*' failed:  Service capability with name='*SharePoint Service*' is not available. Service capability with name='*More specific SharePoint Service name*' is not available.`

### 2. Look at SharePoint Store JSON response

If you don't have access to ULS logs, then this method can sometimes be helpful. What you need to do is monitor network traffic (using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), the [Net Panel in FireBug](https://getfirebug.com/network), or some other program) and catch the `AppPrerequisites` tag in a JSON response when you view the app details page in the store.

When you watch the network traffic on the app details page you'll be looking for a request similar to `/_layouts/15/storefront.aspx?task=GetAppDetails...&appid=<app id>...`. Inside the JSON response for that request look for the **PreRequisites** value. It will list some **Capabilitiy ID**'s which you then match with this [app dependancy table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/jj819804.aspx#Explicit) to determine what service you need to add to your SharePoint server.

---

For example, I was running into the `Sorry, this app is not supported on your server` error with a greyed out app in the SharePoint Store. From monitoring the network traffic I saw this in the JSON response:

```
PreRequisites=
    <AppPrerequisites xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest">
        <AppPrerequisite Type="AutoProvisioning" ID="Database" />
        <AppPrerequisite Type="Capability" ID="{7CC11180-92E4-49F4-AF68-A55CA440E761}" />
    </AppPrerequisites>
```

and with that Capability ID I was able to look in the app dependancy table and see in my case I was missing Access Services. So I added a new Access Services application and was then able to add the app from the store to my SharePoint site.