# How do I add Apps from MS Store?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, app

I want to get the CAD viewer app which is free and it supports on prem . https://store.office.com/dwg-viewer-WA104379055.aspx?assetid=WA104379055.

But I see following from my sharepoint sites.
Sorry, this app is not supported on your server

Comment: Look at this forum https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-forum/viewing-autocad-files-on-sharepoint/td-p/6530627

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Appcatalog** Site in your Tenant

Settings -> View All Site Contents -> Add an app

[image]

Please use Web CAD SDK for Sharepoint in Intranet:
http://cadsofttools.com/products/web-cad-sdk/

Comment: Tarun, Thanks for the quick reply. I still get "you can't add this app here"[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLZlH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLZlH.png)

Answer (score 1):

It could be because of the few services which haven't been enabled on your server.
Mainly because of the User Profile Services. Set up the User Profile Services and make sure it is up and running.

If in case, this is not the problem, do let me know and I will install it myself and will let you the names of the other services required for this app.

I have tried installing an Employee Directory app, and the same error message : "**Sorry, this app is not supported on your server**". And once, I have configured the User Profile Services, I was able to install the app. I am also providing links of various other resolutions to the problem which have been faced by other SharePoint Users:

- [SharePoint apps are greyed out](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60122/sharepoint-apps-are-greyed-out)
- ["Sorry this app is not supported on this server" when adding workflow to SharePoint app](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126658/sorry-this-app-is-not-supported-on-this-server-when-adding-workflow-to-sharepo)
- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2013/01/31/how-to-configure-sharepoint-2013-on-premises-deployments-for-apps/
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7db0eaea-881b-4ac0-878e-e0247d976f6f/sorry-this-app-is-not-supported-on-your-server-error-when-attempting-to-install-the-app-on?forum=appsforsharepoint
- https://nearbaseline.com/forums/topic/sorry-this-app-is-not-supported-on-your-server/

Answer (score 0):

- Try to add this app in another site.
- Verify if this account that you attempting to add the app is **site
  collection administrator**.

> **Note :** SharePoint On-premise apps can only be added to sites by Site Collection administrators; increase permission level of the user
>   account attempting to add the app.

Comment: I agree with this. But in that scenario, the message is: "Request your Tenant Administrator for approval" or something similar to this.